# Buffering without overlap using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, buffer, overlapping-features

Goal: Buffering line features, where the buffer "ends" when an other buffer is about to overlap. Simply: Buffering without overlapping and creating a smooth border between the buffer.

My first Approach: buffering and working with thiesen polygons, but the boundary of thiessen is not smooth.

Is there a solution using QGIS?

This is my actual set up.

[image: Buffers with overlap]

Comment: which software are you working with?

Comment: You can Buffer normally and then remove the overlap using Erase (ArcGIS) or Difference (Postgis). Every GIS has this function.

Comment: I use ArcGIS, QGIS, SAGA-GIS. Erase is not a solution, because it would erase one buffer. The goal is something like buffering from both sides toward the "middle". This feature class contains two lines.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution.

Steps as overview:

1. Extract first and last node from lines
2. Buffer those nodes
3. Difference: Buffered Nodes and lines to cut lines out
4. densify vertices of cutted lines
5. Create Voronoi-Polygons and dissolve them by attribute of the lines
6. Buffer lines and dissolve all
7. Intersect Buffered Lines and dissolved Voronoi-Polygon
8. Done

The workflow is a bit long, so I created a video.

[QGIS Buffer line feature without overlapping polygons](https://youtu.be/t6gGrv3vRoM)